# send sms in pdu mode using android

Tags: android

I am developing an application which needs to send sms in pdu mode.

I am using this code but it gives NoSuchElementException on first line.

```
try {
        Method m2 = sms.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("sendRawPdu", pdu.getClass(), pdu.getClass(), piSent.getClass(), piDelivered.getClass());
        m2.setAccessible(true);
        SmsMessage.SubmitPdu pdus = SmsMessage.getSubmitPdu(null, "", "Test", false);


        Object[] arrayOfObject2 = new Object[5];
        arrayOfObject2[0] = pdus.encodedScAddress;
        arrayOfObject2[1] = pdus.encodedMessage;
        arrayOfObject2[2] = piSent;
        arrayOfObject2[3] = piDelivered;
        arrayOfObject2[4] = null;

        try {
            m2.invoke(sms, arrayOfObject2);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it on Lollipop, but there is no method related to `sendRawPdu`

Do a little more thing just print the list of methods available to check if there is any method related to `sendRawPdu`

```
Method[] methods = sms.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
boolean methodAvailable = false;
for(Method m : methods) {
    Log.d("SmsManager", m.toString());
    if(m.toString().contains("sendRawPdu")) {
        methodAvailable = true;
    }
}
```

now you have methodAvailable, if it is true you can send Raw PDU, if not then you can't. `sendRawPdu` was available before JellyBeans. Try to run this on Pre JellyBeans devices.